# I'm trying to prove that $ [\hat L^2, \hat V(\hat r ,\hat p )] = -2i\hbar (i\hbar \hat V - \hat V \times \hat L) $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

First  I prove that:

$$[\hat L, \hat H] = 0$$

with $$\hat H = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\hat V(\hat r)$$

Then, with $\hat V(\hat r,\hat p)$ as a vector:

$$ [\hat L^2, \hat V(\hat r ,\hat p )] = -2i\hbar (i\hbar \hat V - \hat V \times \hat L) $$

I know that:

$$ [\hat x_i,\hat p_j]=i\hbar \delta_{ij} $$
$$ [\hat L_i,\hat x_j]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}\hat x_k$$
$$ [\hat L_i,\hat p_j]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}\hat p_k$$

Comment: Hint: $[\hat{A}\hat{B}, \hat{C}] = \hat{A}[\hat{B}, \hat{C}] + [\hat{A}, \hat{C}]\hat{B}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using the definition $L_i = \epsilon_{ijk}x_j p_k $ but nothing clear shows up.
Then, I tried using the definition that says $ [x_i,V(r,p)]=i\hbar \frac{\partial V}{\partial p_i} $ and $ [p_i,V(r,p)]=i\hbar \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i} $ and find a Bivector but nothing that make me think on the result.

Comment: Potential a vector??